# Is there a way to run an electron app Build?

Tags: electron

I am a very beginner in Electron JS and was working with Fifo Browser Code. I have created the build for the Fifo browser and wanted to run that build through code but hasn't been successful.

I tried running that build using this code:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');


let win;

function createWindow() {
  const startUrl = url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'app.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true,
  });
  
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 644,
    height: 470,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
    }
  });
  
  win.loadURL(startUrl);
  win.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: 'detach' });    
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow()
    }
});
```

When i run this code the window opens and I get the blank screen and in the devTools console i get this error:

[Console Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdgD9.png)

Now How can I run this build?

Comment: Try swapping out `win.loadURL(startUrl);` with `win.loadFile(startFile);` and update your `startUrl` constant to `const startFile = path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'app.html');`. See [`win.loadFile(filePath[, options])`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winloadfilefilepath-options) for more information.